# Most efficient way to pack SVG graphs onto a site?

Tags: html, svg, data-visualization

I'm working on a hobby project linked here: https://conjectory.org/

The site essentially is a collection of SVG graphs that are rendered to the screen.

From a UX standpoint it's kind of frustrating how "wide" the site is, and I would like pack the graphs more efficiently.

Now the SVG protocol, does some nice things like minimize number of edge crossings, and i'd like to preserve that, but instead of having ALL my root nodes at the same height I would them to pack into a region that minimizes the total square area.

### My Ideas:

One approach is to turn each independent tree in this forest into its own SVG object and pack it into a div, then the problem is how do we pack rectangular divs as efficiently as possible in the screen.

But this feels very high effort, (finding a packing algorithm + splitting the SVG into individual bocks), I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: Could you explain what "total square area" means? It's unclear from your question and google's not explaining it either. Do you want to layout the graphs in a square of smallest side-length?

Comment: Yes that’s what I want. Sorry I realized it did not make my intent clear.

Comment: I can't understand much of it, though perhaps you'll get some utility out of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem - it will unfortunately almost certainly require splitting the graphs into their own seperate images, though perhaps the Extensions->Web->Slicer menu items in Inkscape would expediate the chopping-up part of the task.